# Audio waveform selection in Swing

Tags: java, swing, audio, waveform

I'm working on audio editor. Each waveform is drawn in own JPanel. Those JPanels are inside another JPanel, which is a container for waveforms and the timeline. And this container is in a JScrollPane.

Now I have to write view for Selection class and I don't know which Swing component will be the best. Selection should be drawn **over waveforms** (or all container), should be quite **transparent** and **should be draggable** (not resizable, just draggable) along time axis.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 4):

When I did this exact thing I subclassed JComponent.  Reason is a Waveform viewer component really isn't a container.  You aren't going to set a layout manager, or have children you add to it, etc.  You could have special components that might be like children, say flags, annotations, etc, but they probably won't act like Swing components.  Besides using your own version of these makes it really easy to create lighter weight components than swing.  In fact I had most of those concepts: 1 or more selections, loop points, flags, play head, etc.

My component worked something like this:

```
public class AudioView extends JComponent implements Scrollable {

   private float samplesPerPixel = 1.0f;
   private PlayHeadOverlay playHead;
   private List<WaveformOverlay> overlays = new ArrayList<WaveformOverlay>();
   private WaveformOverlay selected = null;

   protected void paintComponent( Graphics graphics ) {
      ... // all the math for drawing the waveform
      for( WaveformOverlay overlay : overlays ) {
          overlay.paint( graphics );
      }
   }
}

public abstract class WaveformOverlay implements EventDispatcher {
   public boolean isVisible() { return visible; }
   public void setVisible( visible ) { this.visible = visible; }

   public abstract paint( Graphics graphics );

   public boolean isWithin(Point point) {
      return false; // subclasses override this so we can know if they are inside the overlay (eg mouse events).
   }

   public String getToolTipText() {
      return null; // override this if you want a tooltip upon mouse over
   }
}
```

This is roughly what each overlay implements.  There are several other methods for handling event dispatching, listening, etc.  Selections, flags, playhead, annotations all implement WaveformOverlay.  Inside the AudioView.paintComponent() method delegates a portion of it's drawing to each overlay within the visible view.

Same concept is applied for mouse motion events, mouse clicks, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The Question & Answer, [Finding local Minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633320/finding-local-minimum/6636749), may suggest an approach to dragging a selection in a waveform.

Addendum: To effect *z*-ordering, consider a [layered pane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html).

Comment: I know how to find start and end of the selection, bocause I already have it implemented in Selection model. The problem is, that I don't know what swing component should I use. I don't know how to make something like another layer over existing JPanels. I am a webdeveloper, to I think about it as another div with higher z-index;).